# Manually linked libraries can't find React headers because header search paths don't include pod directory

Tags: xcode, react-native

I'm having trouble updating to React Native v60.4. I have React being installed via Pods and all of it's dependencies along with a few other packages. These all work fine. The issue is when I manually link a library in build phases. The only way I can get this to work is by adding `/ios/Pods/Headers/Public` into their `headers search paths` but that will get wiped every time I run yarn

This used to be fine in older versions because I would remove the pod React target in favour of a manually linked libReact.a. Now that's an issue because I can't remove the `React-Core` target so I get duplicate symbol errors.

```
target 'AppName' do
   pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
   pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
   pod 'React-DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
   pod 'React-fishhook', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/fishhook'
   pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
   pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
   pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
   pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
   pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
   pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
   pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
   pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
   pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
   pod 'React-RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket'
   pod 'React-RCTPushNotification', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/PushNotificationIOS'

   pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
   pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
   pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
   pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
   pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

   pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
   pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
   pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

    pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 4.13.0'
    pod 'Intercom'
    pod 'react-native-camera', path: '../node_modules/react-native-camera'
    pod 'react-native-intercom', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-intercom'
    pod 'react-native-shimmer', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-shimmer'
    pod 'react-native-twilio-video-webrtc', path: '../node_modules/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc'
    pod 'react-native-document-picker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-document-picker'
    pod 'Stripe', '~> 13.2.0'
    pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'
    pod 'RNRate', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-rate/ios'
    pod 'ReactNativePermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'
    inherit! :search_paths

  pod 'react-native-webview', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-webview'
  pod 'RNDeviceInfo', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-device-info'
  pod 'react-native-maps', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'RNStoreReview', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-store-review/ios'
  pod 'RCTRestart', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-restart/ios'
  pod 'rn-fetch-blob', :path => '../node_modules/rn-fetch-blob'

  pod 'BugsnagReactNative', :path => '../node_modules/bugsnag-react-native'

end
```

When building, I keep getting:

```
node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h:10:9: 'React/RCTDefines.h' file not found
```

Comment: How did you solve this?